# Excel Solver / Linear Programming: How to set constraint enforcing the maximum 'distance' between high vs low decision variables?

Tags: excel, linear-programming, solver

Suppose I have a set of binary decision variables (e.g. an 1 row array of 10 price points from $1, $2, ..., $10).

The optimization itself is not important, except I must choose no more than 4 price points. That constraint is solved, sum up the binaries and constrain the sum to be <= 4.

Another constraint is required, however, which is stumping me. I need to create a constraint where the highest and lowest price points of whatever was chosen is no greater than a value I enter in a cell. Suppose I enter "4" in the cell, then all of the price points must be within $4 of each other (e.g. $1 cannot be chosen with $6 or higher, $5 is OK).

Example: Maximum Price Distance = $5 (this is a variable cell)

```
DV: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] is OK
DV: [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] is NOT OK
```

How do I do this in a way that is linear (cannot use MAX(), MIN(), or IF() functions)?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
 Maxprice >= x(i) * price(i)
 Minprice <= x(i) * price(i)+(1-x(i))*M
 Maxprice - minprice <= maxdifference
```

Where `M` is a constant `M=max(i,price(i))`.

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate on this? Do I compute the max price for all possible binary x(i) * price(i)? In the above example, wouldn't I be left with 10 max prices and 10 min prices?

Comment: The first is 10 inequalities, the second also 10 inequalities, the third is only one inequality.

Comment: There is only one maxprice and minprice. Otherwise I would have indexed it by i.

Comment: Are Maxprice and Minprice additional decision variables?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. Sorry I need 15 chars.

Comment: I like this idea, but I'm probably setting this up incorrectly. Solver is returning an infeasible solution (whereas the base case worked).

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. This should not be too complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164088/discussion-between-wibble-and-erwin-kalvelagen).